# Does Python's read() always return requested size except at EOF?

Tags: python, file-io

Does the Python read() method behave like C's read? Might it return less than the requested number of bytes *before* the last chunk of the file is reached? Or does it guarantee to always return the full amount of bytes when those bytes exist to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CPython, it will always return the number of bytes requested, unless EOF is reached.

Comment: I.e. don't assume it, since your code will be dependent on CPython. Also I don't think this is true for all file-like objects.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: This heavily depends on what is being read. The guarantee comes from the [io.BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader). Unbuffered reads are subject to the OS semantics which **usually** do not make this guarantee even if they succeed in reading all requested bytes 99% of the time. I've personally seen under-reads for unbuffered file objects while reading through 1TB data file.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Python Standard library says this about file.read([size]):

`Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes).` If the size argument is negative or omitted, `read all data until EOF is reached`. ... `An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately`. ... Also note that `when in non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.`

Comment: Yes, I read that, but it does say "read at most", not "read exact number of bytes requested unless hitting the EOF".

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what is being read.

By default python uses a [io.BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedRea) but will not use one if you explicitly switch off buffering:

```py
with open(__file__, "rb", buffering=0) as file:
    print(f"Unbuffered file type {type(file).__name__}")

with open(__file__, "rb", buffering=10) as file:
    print(f"Explicit buffered file type {type(file).__name__}")

with open(__file__, "rb") as file:
    print(f"Default [buffered] file type {type(file).__name__}")
```

```
Unbuffered file type FileIO
Explicit buffered file type BufferedReader
Default [buffered] file type BufferedReader
```

According to the documentation, the `io.BufferedReader` will only read less if it hits the EOF or the underlying OS call would block:

> read(size=- 1, /)
>
> Read and return size bytes, or if size is not given
> or negative, until EOF or if the read call would
> block in non-blocking mode.

That means if you are reading a regular file, the BufferedReader will only read less if it hits the EOF because regular files do not "block", even if they take time to return.

However if you are reading from a *nix "FIFO" (pipe) then the io.BufferedReader will return less than requested if there is no data waiting in the pipe.

If you disable buffering altogether then `read()` will return whatever the OS returns.  Even if you are reading regular files, this can return less than you requested.  Be very careful when disabling buffering.

Comment: Thanks, this is much more useful than the accepted answer! I came here because I'd observed what you described with pipes, and wanted to confirm this was expected behavior.